# Remove label from custom field

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I have magento 2.1.1 and I want to remove custom field label which is added by 3th party module. In that module appropriate xml file is placed by path *Namespace_ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*
I copied that file by path *app/design/frontend/mynamespace/custom-theme/Namespace_ModuleName/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*
and it works because I can easily overwrite label text in this file. But  I need to remove label at all. I tried to just remove a line which add label but seems like original file add it during xml merging. 
Is it possible to remove it? Here is xml fragment

[image]

Comment: Yes you simply have to define that label node.

`<item name="label" />`

Comment: @Himanshu doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @fortegente I know is not ideal, but you could hide it via css. Also, maybe it is rendered in the template via knockoutjs, is hard to say as it is a custom module.